# Is MongoDB faster for storing data than pandas read/write to_excel?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pandas

I am developing a database of information and currently storing the data in various sheet in multiple XLSX files and considering switching my data to a MongoDB database. Is it quicker read/write for MongoDB than read/write for Pandas? Is Pandas just a nice way to analyze a relational database versus storing information in excel files?

EDIT:

Suppose I have an excel file with multiple sheets and each sheet has 1,000+ lines of floating point data with 5 columns and I read in the XLSX, parse it.

```
df = pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx")
```

would it be faster/more efficient to pull the data directly from a mongoDB database than the read/write of Pandas.

Comment: I'm not sure what the ask is. "Quicker" is always relative to something, e.g. your hardware, your use case, etc. "Database of information" is not very specific. Pandas is mainly a data analysis tool, it's unclear why you want to use Pandas to store anything. Please rephrase the question in an actionable manner, e.g. where the answer is not opinion-based.

Comment: I am specifically speaking of storing historical price data from Bittrex in MongoDB versus storing it in an excel file

Comment: From your updated question: all things being equal (hardware etc.), getting data from a database will almost always be faster than reading an excel file (assuming the proper schema design, among others). This is what a database is designed for. Reading excel file will always involve reading and interpreting the contents, which is at least another layer of processing. However this is assuming many things are equal, which may or may not be the case in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to compare running time of the code snippet you provided,
on your hardware,
with running time of a similar mongo snippet,
on your hardware.